# How To Change ASP.NET Website Theme Dynamically

Tags: asp.net

I have a code like

```
   <configuration>
        <system.web>
              <pages Theme="Themename" />
        </system.web>
   </configuration>
```

Now how we can change the theme value runtime.

I want the user select the theme from dropdownlist & selected theme sets to the web.config file and then applied thrughout the project.

Answer (score 4):

If you would change it globally, every user would get the theme that the last user chose.

You will have to store the choise that the user made in a user specific storage, like the Session state:

```
Session["Theme"] = "ThemeName";
```

Then you will have to set the theme in the Page_Init event for every page:

```
public void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs args) {
   string theme = Session["Theme"] as String;
   if (theme != null) {
      Page.Theme = theme;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can never change theme after Page_Init of the page lifecycle.